# Starting Dialog when Tab is clicked in Android TabHost

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-tabhost

I've been researching in ways to start a dialog instead of a whole other activity when a tab is pressed.

The functionality will be very similar to the "+" tab in the GroupMe App.
http://images.brighthub.com/e3/4/e3491200866ea0263d781334943c6859ce13d029_large.jpg

An alternative solution would be to use a plain bar with no tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that when you change the selected tab.

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends  TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{  
.....

mTabHost. setOnTabChangedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

             // here you can show the Dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: After the dialog I would like to return to the tab the user was at previously so it truly acts as a dialog view. Is there a way to do that programmatically.

Comment: Yes you can dismiss the dialog.